# Xpath parsing xml files with inner childs

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an xml file using Xpath. Below is my piece of code for it.

```
File inputFile = new File("package.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            String expression = "/package/group/table";
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    System.out.println("Table name : " + eElement.getAttribute("name"));
                    System.out.println("Default : " + eElement.getAttribute("default"));
                    System.out.println("ID : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));

                }
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The XML file use for processing is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package name="FBNK.SECTOR">
  <group name="FBNK.SECTOR">
    <table name="FBNK.SEC" default="FBNK.SECTOR" id="SECTOR.CODE">
      <column name="DESCRIPTION" size="35" type="A" position="1" singlemulti="M" subvalue="NO" mvgroupno="1" descriptor="C" />
    </table>
    <table name="FBNK.SECTOR$HIS" default="FBNK.SECTOR$HIS" id="SECTOR.CODE">
      <column name="AUDIT.DATE.TIME" size="50" position="17" singlemulti="S" subvalue="NO" descriptor="C" />
    </table>
  </group>
  <group name="funds.transfer">
    <table name="FBNK.FUNDS.TRANSFER" default="FBNK.FUNDS.TRANSFER" id="REF.NO">
      <column name="AC.CHG.REQ.ID" size="35" type="A" position="147" singlemulti="S" subvalue="NO" descriptor="C" />
      <column name="TREASURY.RATE" size="16" type="R" position="16" singlemulti="S" subvalue="NO" descriptor="C" />
    </table>
  </group>
</package>
```

Currently my problem is i am getting only the expression found under **/package/group/table.**  Can u pls help me to get the same package**/group/table/column** how to get using Xpath ? Thanks in advance..

Comment: `/package/group/table/column` would address all the columns, but maybe you want to retrieve the columns of the table you're currently handling? If so, using `column` from the context of the previously found `table` `Node` would work.

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thanks for your swift response. Could you elaborate with piece of code using the above on how to get the columns from the previously found table node..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to retrieve the columns of the currently handled table (referenced as `nNode`) :

```
NodeList columnList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("column").evaluate(nNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```